# Can't resolve zxing-kotlin and opencv

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

I wanted to import zxing:kotlin, opencv and camerax to my build.gradle file in my dependencies but I'm getting the following error when i'm trying to build my gradle:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.zxing:zxing-kotlin:3.3.3
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Failed to resolve: org.opencv:opencv-platform-agnostic:4.8.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

com.github.fornewid:camerax-view:2.1.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

I've gone online to find the correct versions to update my dependencies versions but i'm not getting any information about them.

Comment: Could you please tell where did you find those dependencies, so we can check docs to help you? Can't google it